# SGEN doesn't work after recompiling framework from 2.0 to 4.5.2

Tags: .net

I have recompiled my project from 2.0 to 4.5.2 and post build event is:

### "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\sgen.exe" /force "$(TargetPath)". Whenever I try to build it I get the following error

Error   1   An attempt was made to load an assembly with an incorrect format: d:\projects\samplekey\samplekey\bin\release\samplekey.dll.    D:\Projects\SampleKey\SampleKey\EXEC

Error 2: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\sgen.exe" /force "D:\Projects\SampleKey\SampleKey\bin\Release\SampleKey.dll"" exited with code 1

---

What the problem is. Any ideas?.

Comment: Build error is resolved: Changed "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\sgen.exe" to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX4.5.1 Tools\sgen.exe

Answer (score 0):

Build error is resolved: Changed "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\sgen.exe" to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX4.5.1 Tools\sgen.exe